# Supporting multiple languages in a Winforms application

Tags: c#, winforms, internationalization, resources, globalization

I've almost finished my C# application; the only thing left to do is to implement multiple language support.

I've already created resource files which hold strings for a few languages for all the text displayed on screen.

Example of my English Resource file:

```
Name                    |  Value                       | Comment
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
lblName                 |   Name:                      |  Name EN
```

Example of my Dutch Resource file:

```
Name                    |  Value                       | Comment
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
lblName                 |  Naam:                       | Name NL
```

How can I bind the field `Value` to the [`Text`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0cs4xb3d.aspx) property of my [`Label`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.label.aspx) (`lblName`)?

I'm using .NET Framework 3.5.

Comment: That totally depends on the GUI framework, which you did not specify.

Comment: Look at this article [Localization process by using resource files in .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/79397/Localization-process-by-using-resource-files-in-NE)

Comment: Here is a an MSDN walkthough for localizing WinForms applications: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y99d1cd3%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: I guess you have noticed by now that multi language support is NOT something to think about when you are nearly done... :)

Comment: It isn't a big application, and I google a bit for some explanation, but couldn't find a good tutorial, I only saw that almost everyone used a new Resource file, so I did too:)

Answer (score 1):

I know this question have been ask a long time ago but since there was no answer here's what I suggest:

To access a resource file in C# you can use a [ResourceManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/system.resources.resourcemanager(v=vs.110).aspx).
First create your resource manager depending on the curent language.
You have two options for this. You can use a switch or if statement (if the language is determined by a menu) or use localization to use the current culture of the computer. Finally, with both ways you can then call the GetString() method providing the key which I believe in your case is lblName.

N.B: In the example bellow I use the first method which is retrieving the language from a menu.

```
string selectedLanguage = comboBoxLang.Text; // Comes from a menu option
string resourceFile = string.Empty;

/***/
Logic to retrieve the proper resourceFile depending on the selectedLanguage.
/***/

ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager(resourceFile, Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

// Set your label text.
lblName.Text = rm.GetString("lblName");
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
<asp:Label runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:DutchLanguage, Value %>"></asp:Label>
```

Comment: I'am using Windows Forms and it is an Desktop c# application, not a webpage(ASP).

Comment: You mention C# application, but did not specified it from the begining

Comment: Then I should have used: Web application and used the ASP tag and there is a tag: WinForms.

Answer (score -3):

Put the values of different languages in one database table.

Let the user select language.

According to the selection of language fetch the data from database about particular language.

And then bind it with label text.

Comment: That is not the right way to do it I think, the Resource files or not created for nothing

Comment: This is actually a good solution, but for translation of data fetched from database, text cells from lookup tables for example. In this case it's useless. +1 for effort. :)